# SQL is showing every possible combinations instead of showing unique name, order number, quantity and price of total goods ordered

Tags: sql, sql-server

From the Customers, Orders, Order Details, Products tables, display the name, order number, order quantity, and price of goods ordered by German customers.

I have written the following code:

```
SELECT Products.ProductName, Orders.OrderID, [Order Details].Quantity, [Order Details].Total_Price
FROM Products, [Order Details], Orders, Customers
WHERE Country= 'Germany'
```

But the result is something different[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNkxX.png)
It is showing every possible combinations, instead of showing unique name, order number, quantity and price of total goods ordered. What should I do?

Comment: You should use correct joins - your comma joins don't have the corresponding condition in the where clause which is one reason you shouldn't use them.

Comment: Microsoft docs on using JOIN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver16.  You need to use JOINs between the tables to establish the correct relationships between the data .... for example, Order Details may JOIN to Products using a "Product ID" column.  Orders may JOIN to Order Details using an "Order ID" column, and may also JOIN to Customers using a "Customer ID" column.  You'll need to interrogate your table structures and determine the relationships between them - then set the required JOIN criteria

Comment: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems